# Extract substrings from a file and store them in shell variables

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, text-parsing

I am working on a script. I have a file called test.txt whose contents are as follows:

```
a. parent = 192.168.1.2
b. child1 = 192.168.1.21
c. child2 = 192.154.1.2
```

I need to store the values in three different variables called parent, child1and child2 as follows and then my script will use these values:

```
parent = 192.168.1.2
child1= 192.168.1.21
child2= 192.154.1.2
```

How can I do that using sed or awk? I know there is a way to extract substrings using awk function substr but my particular requirement is tostore them in variables as mentioned above. Thanks

Comment: You mean store it in an array by splitting the file contents?

Comment: its a shell script. Sorry for the confusion. I cannot store them in an array. I need to store them in the variables only due to some constraint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this if you're using bash:

```
$ declare $(awk '{print $2"="$4}' file)
$ echo "$parent"
192.168.1.2
```

If the file contained white space in the values you want to init the variables with then you'd just have to set IFS to a newline before invoking declare, e.g. (simplified the input file to highlight the important part of white space on the right of the `=` signs):

```
$ cat file
parent=192.168.1.2 is first
child1=192.168.1.21 comes after it
child2=and then theres 192.154.1.2

$ IFS=$'\n'; declare $(awk -F'=' '{print $1"="$2}' file)
$ echo "$parent"
192.168.1.2 is first
$ echo "$child1"
192.168.1.21 comes after it
```

Comment: Nicely done; didn't occur to me that you could do it with a single command substitution.

Comment: can you please explain how this is working and how is the value even getting asisgned to the variable parent?

Comment: `awk` outputs `parent=192.168.1.2` etc. so then `declare` is called with that sequence of assignments as it's arguments, e.g. `declare parent=192.168.1.2` and as such it declares the variable `parent` as having the value `192.168.1.2`. Try the awk command on it's own `awk '{print $2"="$4}' file` and then try the declare command on it's own `declare parent=192.168.1.2 child1=192.168.1.21 child2=192.154.1.2` to see it broken down.

Comment: Yes i understood it. So basically, first I have to store everything in my file in an array and then just do this? Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: No, you are wrong. Just run the command I show on the input file you posted.

Comment: Great to see that the embedded-whitespace scenario is now handled with similar elegance. Caveat: It's tempting to try `IFS=$'\n' declare ...`, i.e. to think that a _command-local_ `$IFS` definition can be used, but that does _not_ work here, because `declare` is a _builtin_, not an external utility. That's why `IFS=$'\n'` is its _own_ command here; with that, however, may come the need to restore the previous `$IFS` value afterward.

Answer (score 1):

[Ed Morton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28889569/45375) is the way to go for the specific problem at hand - elegant and concise.

---

**Update**: Ed has since updated his answer to also provide a solution that correctly deals with variable value values *with embedded spaces* - the original lack of which prompted this answer.

His solution is superior to this one - more concise and more efficient (the only caveat is that you may have to restore the previous `$IFS` value afterward).

*This solution may still be of interest if you need to process variable definitions one by one*, e.g., in order to transform variable values based on other shell functions or variables before assigning them.

---

The following uses bash with process substitution on a simplified problem to process variable definitions one by one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r name val; do # read a name-value pair

    # Assign the value after applying a transformation to it; e.g.:
    # 'value of' -> 'value:'
    declare $name="${val/ of /: }" # `declare "$name=${val/ of /: }"` would work too.

done < <(awk -F= '{print $1, $2}' <<<$'v1=value of v1\nv2=  value of v2')

echo "v1=[$v1], v2=[$v2]" # -> 'v1=[value: v1], v2=[value: v2]'
```

- `awk`'s output lines are read line by line, split into name and value, and declared as shell variables individually.
- Since `read`, which trims by whitespace, is only given *2* variable names to read into, the 2nd one receives everything from the 2nd token _through the end of the line, thus preserving interior whitespace (and, as written, will trim *leading and trailing* whitespace in the process).
- Note that `declare` normally does *not* require a variable reference on the RHS of the assignment (the value) to be double-quoted (e.g. `a=$b`; though it never hurts). In this particular case, however - seemingly because the LHS (the name) is also a variable reference - the double quotes are needed.

Comment: All you really need to handle embedded white space is to set IFS to a newline before calling declare, e.g. `IFS=$'\n'; declare $(awk '{print $2"="$4}' file)`, no need for a loop. I updated my answer to show that.

Comment: @EdMorton: Excellent point. I've updated my answer to point to yours for both scenarios. I've also made a note that the loop approach may still make sense if preprocessing of each definition based on shell functions or variables is needed and modified the code to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

I also got it done finally . Thanks everyone for helping.

```
counter=0
while read line
do
        declare $(echo $line | awk '{print $2"="$4}')
        #echo "$parent"
        if [ $counter = 0 ]
        then
                parent=$(echo $parent)
        fi
        if [ $counter = 1 ]
        then
                child1=$(echo $child)
        else
                child2=$(echo $child)
        fi
        counter=$((counter+1))
done < "/etc/cluster_info.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
eval "$( sed 's/..//;s/  *//g' YourFile )"
```

just a sed equivalent to Ed solution and with an eval instead of declare.